# How to defined jquery in Nodejs inside ejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have starts learning NodeJs and building a sample application. In my application I need to implement an inline editor(Bootstrap Inline editor). For that I included necessary bootstrap-editable and then I start run my application then I am getting,

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined in NodeJs
```

Then I install `npm install jquery` to install jquery and add
var `$ = require('jquery')` inside the **routes** `index.js`.

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  var $ = require("jquery")(window);
    $('#username-<%= sysHead %>').editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk: '<%= row[sysHead] %>',
    url: '/update_systemConfiguration',
    dataType: 'json',
    title: 'Enter username'
  });
  //modify buttons style
  $.fn.editableform.buttons = 
    '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-submit"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm editable-cancel"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';
});
```

But still I am getting the **ReferenceError: $ is not defined in NodeJs** in my browser console.

Comment: include jquery in your main ejs file

Comment: @iambatman I have included var $ = required('jquery') in my app.js and then now I'm getting TypeError: require(...).jsdom is not a function

Comment: Did you any build setups

Comment: @iambatman I have install jquery and jsdom that all I did.

Answer (score 0):

The `jsdom` syntax you're using is outdated and no longer supported. That could be part of the problem.

You can follow these steps to use `jquery` with `jsdom`:

Install via NPM:

```
npm install jsdom --save-dev
npm install jquery --save-dev
```

JavaScript:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM('<html></html>');
var $ = require('jquery')(window);
```